# How to send post request to the below post method using postman rest client

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I just want to know, how to send JSON object to `createTrackInJSON(Track track)`  method, with `@Post` annotation through postman rest client.
here,how to pass JSON object to createTrackInJSON(Track track)  method,with @Post annotation ?

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.mkyong.Track;

@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");
        System.out.println("inside get method . . .");
        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {
        System.out.println("inside post method . .");
        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

}

//Track class is:

public class Track {
String title;
String singer;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSinger() {
    return singer;
}

public void setSinger(String singer) {
    this.singer = singer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

1. Open `Postman`.
2. Enter URL in the URL bar `http://{server:port}/json/metallica/post`.
3. Click `Headers` button and enter `Content-Type` as header and `application/json` in value.
4. Select `POST` from the dropdown next to the URL text box.
5. Select `raw` from the buttons available below URL text box.
6. Select `JSON` from the following dropdown.
7. In the textarea available below, post your request object:

   ```
   {
    "title" : "test title",
    "singer" : "some singer"
   }
   ```
8. Hit `Send`.
9. Refer to screenshot below:
   [image]

Answer (score 12):

**JSON:-**

For POST request using json object it can be configured by selecting

Body -> raw -> application/json

[image: POST JSON object using POSTMAN]

**Form Data(For Normal content POST):-** multipart/form-data

For normal POST request (using multipart/form-data) it can be configured by selecting

Body -> form-data

[image: POST multipart/form-data using POSTMAN]

Answer (score 3):

The Interface of Postman is changing acccording to the updates.

So You can get full information about postman can get Here.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue .
I passed my data as key->value in "Body" section by choosing "form-data" option and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open postman app
2.Enter the URL in the URL bar in postman app along with the name of the design.Use slash(/) after URL to give the design name.
3.Select POST from the dropdown list from URL textbox.
4.Select raw from buttons available below the URL textbox.
5.Select JSON from the dropdown.
6.In the text area enter your data to be updated and enter send.
7.Select GET from dropdown list from URL textbox and enter send to see the updated result.