# Spring MVC: How to set body parameter in request browser and how to get this body parameters in controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I followed may links and found I need to use `@Requestbody` annotation and I need to set `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in header under  `@RequestMapping` annotation. But I did not find any example like how can I set these body parameters in browser and get in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", headers="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void login(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServiceException {
    // I need username and password body parameters value in controller
    }
```

Comment: You can make an [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call and test your url.

Comment: And default `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` when calling the service using ajax.

Comment: For `@Requestbody`, you can refer this [`SO question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring)

Comment: thanks Naman for quick response. Can you please clear the if I used body parameters types as josn then I must to return response in json as well or it can be xml or types in SPRING?

Comment: Yes, if you want the json response, then you should return json, why would you return xml?

Comment: I am returning the joson response. I just want to confirm if I pass body params in json then response must be return in json?

Comment: For that you need to use @ResponseBody. Refer this http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like `Postman` client in the browser.

You can install it from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). After installation, you can refer to answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364862/how-to-send-post-request-to-the-below-post-method-using-postman-rest-client/29365126#29365126) to know how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Promod, I got the idea about setting body parameters in browser. Do you have any idea about if I used body parameters types as josn then I must to return response in json as well or it can be xml or types in SPRING?