# How to get data returned from an API after sending a POST request using POSTMAN?

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I am trying to get the data returned from the API using the POST method also I need to pass some parameters to it. I am trying this since a long time by putting the data in the body and also tried to put it in form-data in postman. I just want to test it to see what it returns and how it works. The API link:-

```
doorhopper.in/api/user/localMarket
```

The params I need to send are :-

```
"phone":if available
"latitude":if available
"longitude":if available
"regId":using any clientside logic
"token":if logged in we get a token on login
"city":"Silchar",
"category":"Swadeshi",
"categoryId":"1007"
"limit":"15"
```

I already checked a lot of answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364862/how-to-send-post-request-to-the-below-post-method-using-postman-rest-client) but doesnt help:-

I am getting this everytime:-

```
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:255
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(242): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(599): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(588): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(577): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 {main}Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function send() on null in /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/public/index.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 {main}Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:112
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/DoorhopperServer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:112
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Comment: Whats response so far?

Comment: check the edit above