# How do i create a POST request using jax -rs

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I have two classes PlaylistResource which has a method createPlaylist which takes an object of type PlaylistRequest. I want to create a POST request on localhost:9999/playlists I am using Postman and I am not sure how to pass the object of PlaylistRequest which is request to the method createPlaylist.

```
@XmlType(propOrder= {"title", "artistSeeds", "numberOfSongs"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PlaylistRequest {

    private String title = "";
    @XmlElement(name = "seeds")
    private List<String> artistSeeds;
    @XmlElement (name = "size")
    private int numberOfSongs = 0;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<String> getArtistSeeds() {
        return artistSeeds;
    }

    public void setArtistSeeds(List<String> artistSeeds) {
        this.artistSeeds = artistSeeds;
    }

    public int getNumberOfSongs() {
        return numberOfSongs;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSongs(int numberOfSongs) {
        this.numberOfSongs = numberOfSongs;
    }
}
```

The other class:

```
@Path("playlists")
public class PlaylistResource implements PlaylistApi {

    @Override
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createPlaylist(PlaylistRequest request) {

        if(request == null) {
            System.out.println("Was here");
            throw new ClientRequestException(new ErrorMessage("no parameter passed."));
        }

        try {
            List<Song> playList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> artistsIds = new ArrayList<>();
            ArtistResource artistsResources = new ArtistResource();
            int playlistDefaultSize = 10;

            int i = 0;
            do {
                playList.add(songs.get(i));
                i++;
            }while( i < playlistDefaultSize);

            Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
            playlist.setTitle(request.getTitle());
            playlist.setSize(songs.size());
            playlist.setTracks(playList);

            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).entity(playlist).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RemoteApiException(new ErrorMessage(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, You mean you want to know how to test post method with raw payload in the postman? Correct ?

If yes, 

You can watch this video  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYQyqf-DtCQ
or 
It has clear explanation here : https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send post request to the below post method using postman rest client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364862/how-to-send-post-request-to-the-below-post-method-using-postman-rest-client)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `JSON` object in `Body` of request, select `Raw Json` in `Postman` and paste the following object:

**NOTE**: Add a key `Content-Type` and set its value to `application/json` in `Header` of Request

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "artistSeeds": [
    "string1",
    "string2"
  ],
  "numberOfSongs": 0
}
```

**HEADER**
[image: Header]
**BODY**
[image: Body]

Comment: I have tried this but it returns 500 internal server error.

Comment: 500 internal server means you have some problem in code, now just read the exception trace and see what is the issue in code

Comment: It is returning 400 bad request. The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.

Comment: did you specify content type in header?

Answer (score 0):

Change this parameter from data class to string,

`public Response createPlaylist(PlaylistRequest request) {`

to

`public Response createPlaylist(String request) {`

then convert it using GSON into your data class.

```
PlaylistRequest request = new Gson().fromJson(request, new TypeToken<PlaylistRequest >(){}.getType());
```

Comment: why he needs to do it? when jersey can map json to object itself using some library?

Comment: its just another way to do it. for rest API GSON Libary is a must for me :)