# Parse data from Vue to express

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, parsing

If I have some data in my Vue I want to parse to my express server, how can this be done? E.g. in the example below, I want to parse what I currently console log in my vue function, to the variable "id" on my server side

```
expressApp.post('/delete' , function (request, response) {

    const id = request.body.id;
    console.log(id)

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

            if (err) throw err;
            let dbo = db.db(dbName);

            dbo.collection("Members").deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                db.close();
            });
        });
    response.redirect('/agileApp');
    });


t: function (index) {
            fetch(membersUrl).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (data) {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("id", data[index]._id);
                for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
                    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
                }

                fetch(deleteUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
expressApp.post('/delete' , function (request, response) {

    const id = request.body.id; // <--- get id from the request body

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

            if (err) throw err;
            let dbo = db.db(dbName);

            dbo.collection("Members").deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                db.close();
            });
        });
    response.redirect('/agileApp');
    });


t: function (index) {
            fetch(membersUrl).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (data) {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("id", data[index]._id);

                fetch('/delete', {
                  method: 'POST', // <---fetch POST method
                  body: formData
                })
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It says "const id" is undefined though.

Comment: it maybe another issue in your express app.

Comment: did you set body-parser ?

Comment: Yes I should have npm installed body-parser. Is this the correct way to call it: 

"<form action="/delete" method="post">

                        <button type="submit" class="buttons btn btn-outline-danger" @click="ts(index)"><i class="fa">&#xf014;</i> Delete</button>

</form>

Comment: yes, to check if your backend express app is working properly, try to request /delete api using postman.

Comment: Well, when I try and console.log the formData variable it does not show my the ID. Could this be the error perhaps?

Comment: no, it's not the error, to see the formdata correctly, check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata

Comment: Okay thanks. After inspected this way, the formData is correct I can see. However, it still says undefined when I try running it..

Comment: Could it be that the id should be ObjectId type as it's the autogenereted MongoDB ObjectId that is called for the deleteOne?

Comment: no, send it as a string, you can get the specific mongodb row according to the id anyway.

Comment: Okay. I've just update my post to my current code. The console log on the client side show the correct id, objectid but the console.log on the server side shows undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: first, try to send api request by postman to your backend api.

Comment: It looks fine in api request postman. Just checked it.

Comment: try with this in vue code.
...{  method: 'POST', headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },  body: json.stringify({id: ...}) }

Comment: Okay. I've never used it before tbh, so just took a quick look at how to send basic request there.

Comment: Attached ss below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364862/how-to-send-post-request-to-the-below-post-method-using-postman-rest-client/29365126

Comment: Thank you. I've just attached the response below